# How to preserve pistachios?

Tags: food-preservation, nuts

Its the pistachios season in my country (Lebanon), which is famous worldwide with its nuts Roasters and varieties.

[image]

I have more than 5 kilos of fresh unpeeled seasonal pistachios. What should I do to preserve them for at least 6 months ? Peel them and into the fridge or should I roast them before and keeping them inside a container for later uses ?

Comment: I'd be concerned about sticking them in the fridge raw. Too much moisture around: https://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/Salmonella/ucm273482.htm

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Yeah. It's better to roast them few minutes in the stove, dry them a little bit more, and then into the fridge.

Comment: You should ship them to me.  ;-)

Comment: You would just eat them ? Hahaha.